# Airflow run_as_user permission denied

Tags: airflow

I am running airflow `2.4.3` in a single machine, airflow is installed in a python virtualenv, the airflow_home is `/wwx/airflow`.

***My DAG:***

```
default_args = {
        'owner': 'talend',
        'start_date': datetime(2023, 2, 1),
        'retries': 5,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
        'run_as_user': 'talend'
}

dag = DAG(
    'dag_fetch_public_holiday',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Fetch public holiday and save to csv file.',
    schedule_interval='0 6 * * *',
    catchup=False,
    tags=['wwx', 'elt']
)

download_csv = PythonOperator(task_id='task_download_csv', python_callable=download_public_holiday_csv, dag=dag)
```

***DAG description:***

The dag is owned and run by a user `talend`, this user is created in both OS and airflow level. In OS level, the user has group airflow, sudo; in airflow level, the user is admin role.

Inside the dag there is a PythonOperator task to save csv to a folder, it is expected that the csv file will be created and owned by the `talend` user.

***Problem description:***

When I trigger this dag in web UI, it is showing the error permission denied for the dag log folder:

```
*** Reading local file: /wwx/airflow/logs/dag_id=dag_fetch_public_holiday/run_id=scheduled__2023-02-06T06:00:00+00:00/task_id=task_download_csv/attempt=1.log
[2023-02-07, 18:07:23 CST] {taskinstance.py:1165} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: dag_fetch_public_holiday.task_download_csv scheduled__2023-02-06T06:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-02-07, 18:07:23 CST] {taskinstance.py:1165} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: dag_fetch_public_holiday.task_download_csv scheduled__2023-02-06T06:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-02-07, 18:07:23 CST] {taskinstance.py:1362} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-02-07, 18:07:23 CST] {taskinstance.py:1363} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 6
[2023-02-07, 18:07:23 CST] {taskinstance.py:1364} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-02-07, 18:07:23 CST] {taskinstance.py:1383} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): task_download_csv> on 2023-02-06 06:00:00+00:00
[2023-02-07, 18:07:23 CST] {base_task_runner.py:129} INFO - Running on host: vmi1120376.contaboserver.net
[2023-02-07, 18:07:23 CST] {base_task_runner.py:130} INFO - Running: ['sudo', '-E', '-H', '-u', 'talend', 'airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'dag_fetch_public_holiday', 'task_download_csv', 'scheduled__2023-02-06T06:00:00+00:00', '--job-id', '30', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/fetch_public_holiday.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpejvrehc1']
[2023-02-07, 18:07:24 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv /wwx/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/base.py:49 MovedIn20Warning: Deprecated API features detected! These feature(s) are not compatible with SQLAlchemy 2.0. To prevent incompatible upgrades prior to updating applications, ensure requirements files are pinned to "sqlalchemy<2.0". Set environment variable SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20=1 to show all deprecation warnings.  Set environment variable SQLALCHEMY_SILENCE_UBER_WARNING=1 to silence this message. (Background on SQLAlchemy 2.0 at: https://sqlalche.me/e/b8d9)
[2023-02-07, 18:07:24 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv [[34m2023-02-08, 02:07:24 CST[0m] {[34mdagbag.py:[0m537} INFO[0m - Filling up the DagBag from /wwx/airflow/dags/fetch_public_holiday.py[0m
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv Traceback (most recent call last):
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1288, in mkdir
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv     self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/wwx/airflow/logs/dag_id=dag_fetch_public_holiday/run_id=scheduled__2023-02-06T06:00:00+00:00/task_id=task_download_csv'
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv 
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv 
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv Traceback (most recent call last):
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv     sys.exit(main())
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/wwx/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 39, in main
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv     args.func(args)
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/wwx/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 52, in command
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv     return func(*args, **kwargs)
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/wwx/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 103, in wrapper
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv     return f(*args, **kwargs)
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/wwx/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 372, in task_run
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv     ti.init_run_context(raw=args.raw)
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/wwx/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 2503, in init_run_context
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv     self._set_context(self)
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/wwx/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/logging_mixin.py", line 77, in _set_context
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv     set_context(self.log, context)
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/wwx/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/logging_mixin.py", line 213, in set_context
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv     flag = cast(FileTaskHandler, handler).set_context(value)
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/wwx/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_task_handler.py", line 70, in set_context
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv     local_loc = self._init_file(ti)
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/wwx/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_task_handler.py", line 320, in _init_file
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv     Path(directory).mkdir(mode=0o777, parents=True, exist_ok=True)
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1297, in mkdir
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv     if not exist_ok or not self.is_dir():
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1422, in is_dir
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv     return S_ISDIR(self.stat().st_mode)
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1198, in stat
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv     return self._accessor.stat(self)
[2023-02-07, 18:07:27 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 30: Subtask task_download_csv PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/wwx/airflow/logs/dag_id=dag_fetch_public_holiday/run_id=scheduled__2023-02-06T06:00:00+00:00/task_id=task_download_csv'
[2023-02-07, 18:07:28 CST] {local_task_job.py:159} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2023-02-07, 18:07:28 CST] {taskinstance.py:2623} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
[2023-02-07, 18:39:50 CST] {taskinstance.py:1165} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: dag_fetch_public_holiday.task_download_csv scheduled__2023-02-06T06:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-02-07, 18:39:50 CST] {taskinstance.py:1165} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: dag_fetch_public_holiday.task_download_csv scheduled__2023-02-06T06:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-02-07, 18:39:50 CST] {taskinstance.py:1362} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-02-07, 18:39:50 CST] {taskinstance.py:1363} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 6
[2023-02-07, 18:39:50 CST] {taskinstance.py:1364} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-02-07, 18:39:51 CST] {taskinstance.py:1383} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): task_download_csv> on 2023-02-06 06:00:00+00:00
[2023-02-07, 18:39:51 CST] {base_task_runner.py:129} INFO - Running on host: vmi1120376.contaboserver.net
[2023-02-07, 18:39:51 CST] {base_task_runner.py:130} INFO - Running: ['sudo', '-E', '-H', '-u', 'talend', 'airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'dag_fetch_public_holiday', 'task_download_csv', 'scheduled__2023-02-06T06:00:00+00:00', '--job-id', '32', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/fetch_public_holiday.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmp26yeooeq']
[2023-02-07, 18:39:53 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv /wwx/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/base.py:49 MovedIn20Warning: Deprecated API features detected! These feature(s) are not compatible with SQLAlchemy 2.0. To prevent incompatible upgrades prior to updating applications, ensure requirements files are pinned to "sqlalchemy<2.0". Set environment variable SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20=1 to show all deprecation warnings.  Set environment variable SQLALCHEMY_SILENCE_UBER_WARNING=1 to silence this message. (Background on SQLAlchemy 2.0 at: https://sqlalche.me/e/b8d9)
[2023-02-07, 18:39:54 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv [[34m2023-02-08, 02:39:54 CST[0m] {[34mdagbag.py:[0m537} INFO[0m - Filling up the DagBag from /wwx/airflow/dags/fetch_public_holiday.py[0m
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv Traceback (most recent call last):
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1288, in mkdir
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv     self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/wwx/airflow/logs/dag_id=dag_fetch_public_holiday/run_id=scheduled__2023-02-06T06:00:00+00:00/task_id=task_download_csv'
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv 
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv 
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv Traceback (most recent call last):
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv     sys.exit(main())
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/wwx/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 39, in main
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv     args.func(args)
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/wwx/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 52, in command
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv     return func(*args, **kwargs)
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/wwx/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 103, in wrapper
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv     return f(*args, **kwargs)
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/wwx/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 372, in task_run
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv     ti.init_run_context(raw=args.raw)
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/wwx/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 2503, in init_run_context
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv     self._set_context(self)
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/wwx/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/logging_mixin.py", line 77, in _set_context
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv     set_context(self.log, context)
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/wwx/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/logging_mixin.py", line 213, in set_context
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv     flag = cast(FileTaskHandler, handler).set_context(value)
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/wwx/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_task_handler.py", line 70, in set_context
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv     local_loc = self._init_file(ti)
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/wwx/airflow/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_task_handler.py", line 320, in _init_file
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv     Path(directory).mkdir(mode=0o777, parents=True, exist_ok=True)
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1297, in mkdir
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv     if not exist_ok or not self.is_dir():
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1422, in is_dir
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv     return S_ISDIR(self.stat().st_mode)
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1198, in stat
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv     return self._accessor.stat(self)
[2023-02-07, 18:40:00 CST] {base_task_runner.py:111} INFO - Job 32: Subtask task_download_csv PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/wwx/airflow/logs/dag_id=dag_fetch_public_holiday/run_id=scheduled__2023-02-06T06:00:00+00:00/task_id=task_download_csv'
[2023-02-07, 18:40:01 CST] {local_task_job.py:159} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2023-02-07, 18:40:01 CST] {taskinstance.py:2623} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Then I have examined the problematic folder and found it is permission 700.

I could `chmod 777` to the folder manually, however, if there are other new dags/tasks, any new dag/task folder is automatically created with permission 700 and I have to manually chmod.

***What I have tried:***

I have followed https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.10/security.html?highlight=impersonation#impersonation

- Added the following line to /etc/sudoers

```
airflow ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

- Using sudo to start webserver and scheduler

```
sudo sh -c 'export AIRFLOW_HOME=/wwx/airflow; /wwx/airflow/venv/bin/airflow scheduler -D'
sudo sh -c 'export AIRFLOW_HOME=/wwx/airflow; /wwx/airflow/venv/bin/airflow webserver -D -p 8090'
```

- Added airflow command to `/usr/local/bin` so that other users can use

```
sudo ln -s /wwx/airflow/venv/bin/airflow /usr/local/bin/airflow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution as follows:

1. Add the user to airflow group.

`usermod -aG airflow <username>`

2. Set the acl of airflow log directory to have files/folders created with group permission rwx, so the dag run user can access these logs

`setfacl -d -m group:airflow:rwx $AIRFLOW_HOME/logs`

I am not sure if this is a intended behavior in airflow when running dag as other users, since I cannot find any hint from the airflow documentation.